# How to browse by category on Deviantart?

Tags: search, deviantart

I can't find anything on the terrible new eclipse version of the website. I can't figure out how to search by category anymore. It used to be that you entered your search term and the categories were right there at the left side of the site. All you had to do was click on them and it would only display results in that category. If you wanted photography you clicked on Photography. If you wanted written works you clicked on Literature. Then you could narrow down your results further with the sub-categories that were under the category. If you wanted fashion or video game concepts you would click Designs & Interfaces then click Fashion or Game Development Art. Even those sub-categories could be narrowed down further with more sub-categories.

I have no idea where Eclipse has hidden the categories and sub-categories. Where are they? If I can't even find them then how do I search in them? Is there some kind of trick or specific thing I need to add to the url now to organize my search results properly? How do I search by the old categories in Deviantart in the new version of the website?

Comment: Try these tutorials on DeviantArt. They helped me. https://www.deviantart.com/jenfruzz/journal/How-to-DeviantArt-Searching-794068640 https://www.deviantart.com/jenfruzz/journal/Smart-Searching-Using-Tags-618538375

Comment: @KyungsunOrr that's not what i asked. I'm looking for how to search the categories.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too today until I ran across the topics section. You can find it here: https://www.deviantart.com/topic
or by clicking on the little telescope on the left hand side of the desktop layout.

Comment: That's not the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I've got nothing then.  It is much more limited for that purpose than the old media search was.